# How far apart should one's feet be in Salaah?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sunnah

I've seen two extremes: some put their feet very close to each other (some group state 4 fingers width apart) and others stand very wide with the feet even further away from their shoulders and it can look arrogant and ugly and they aren't necessarily trying to touch the sides of their feet with the persons standing next to them in congregation. What is the correct position from the Book and Sunnah?

Comment: Yeah and there are these nice guys who don't care to step you on your toes just to have their "own space"!

Comment: I'm guessing this is different for men and women, and different based on school of thought.

Comment: God will not be looking at your feet while you pray. You should focus your prayer in dedication for the praise of your lord, so that God turn towards you with mercy.